# TFS2012 - New Task - "Assigned To" shows people outside the project

Tags: tfs

I am currently testing my new TFS 2012 installation and noticed the following issue when trying to create new tasks.

In the "Assigned To" drop down it shows service and global domain administrator accounts outside as well as team members for this project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKTYb.jpg

Is there a way to only show the team members of the project?

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ecb9cac7-979f-4996-af2b-ea1e729f10d5/manage-users-in-tfsfor-assign-to-field

Basically, you can limit that field to any security group, but you also need to alter the "ALLOWED VALUES" for the field in the process template.